# How to develop an authentication/authorization plugin that I can use for multiple projects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, authlogic

I am a newbie for RoR but I liked it so far. For the current project I
already developed an authenticaion page where the user will be
authenticated before and after login. I know that I will be doing more
projects on RoR in the coming weeks as well and I don't want to copy
paste my codes to enable authentication in my projects. How can I create
an authentication system where I can use it in multiple projects. Are
there any plugins already been developed?

You should also consider that, the authentication system also be on
call (it should be listening everytime the user goes from one page to
another page by checking if s/he is authorized and also the session
haven't expired yet and so on.). That means I still need the
authentication/authorization system to be there even after login. And
how do I integrate it with other ruby projects I will be working on.  I
hope it makes sense.

The database where users will be authorized might be the same or
different based on the projects.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Authentication/Authorization can be a tricky task. There are many pitfalls, so it would better to use a well tested gem until you're more familiar with it. [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) is a good option, but you can start learning about rolling your own authentication in the [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#top) book if you're inclined.

Comment: I have already implemented the Rails Tutorial you are referring and it works well. However, since my projects are going to be complicated in a while, I wanted to replace my authentication/authorization gem by a well known one. May be with Device. Btw is Device something you can use it as a plug in?can you also alter the code to match your needs? how? Thank you.

Comment: You should really check out the [Devise Readme](http://devise.plataformatec.com.br/), but you can select the modules you're interested in and extend it as it needs to fit your project.